# Why can $p_k$ be written like this ,is mine the same as the photo's?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I saw these formula in this paper,and i don't know why can  the $p_k$ be written like the formula ,in the photo, below
[image]

I derive the formula,and i think $p_k$ should be like this ,according to the first equation

$p_k=\frac{\sum\limits_{j \neq k}(\mathbf h^H_k \bar{\mathbf f_j})^2+\sigma^2_{a_k}+\frac{\sigma^2_{d_k}}{\rho_k}}{(\mathbf h^H_k \bar{\mathbf f_k})^2}\times \bar \gamma_k$ .Is my $p_k$ the same as the paper shown?

By the way,if i want to write the K+1 equations to solve the $\rho_k$,[image]

how do i rewrite the formula? because $\rho$ should be the variable,but there are $\rho_k$ and $\rho_j$,i want to rewrite the K+1 equations as this form

$[\mathbf A ]
\begin{bmatrix}
    \rho_1  \\
    \rho_2  \\
    \rho_3  \\
    \rho_4  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$=P

Comment: The first display has $p_j$ inside the summation. In the formula you give, there's no $p_j$ in the summation. Where did it go?

Comment: Answer, please?

Comment: the range of j is equal to k,but when the j=1,k can't be =1 ,so that is the $p_j$

Comment: Let me try again. The first display has $\sum p_j|h_k^Hf_j|^2$, but then the first formula you typed in has $\sum(h_k^Hf_j)^2$. See the $p_j$ in the first one? See how there's no $p_j$ in the second one? That's a problem, isn't it?

Comment: I say, that's a problem, isn't it?

Comment: well i think the j is in the 1~K.because we only know the j can't be equal to k

Comment: I'm not asking about $j$, I'm asking about $p_j$. It's in the first equation, but then when you write, "according to the first equation, $p_k=\dots$" it's not there in the summation on the right side. How does that happen?

Comment: I mean $p_k=p_1,....,p_j,......p_k$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the $p$ vector that you calculated is the same as the paper's but it's in component form, not in standard matrix-vector form.

Instead of putting the restriction $(j\ne k)$ on the summation, simply add the $k^{th}$ component to the sum and explicitly subtract it outside the sum. This allows the sum to be replaced with a matrix-vector product (specifically $\,Lp\,$ below).

Let $L$ be a full matrix and $G$ be a diagonal matrix (note the "$1+{\rm term}$" that comes from moving the term discussed in the previous paragraph) whose elements are given by
$$\eqalign{
L_{ij} &= \big|h_i^Hf_j\big|^2, \quad
G_{kk} &= \bigg(1+\frac{1}{\gamma_k}\bigg)L_{kk} \cr
}$$
also define a vector with components
$$\eqalign{
v_k &= (\sigma_a^2)_k + \frac{(\sigma_d^2)_k}{\rho_k} \cr
}$$
Now the formula can be written and solved in matrix form.
$$\eqalign{
Gp-Lp &= v \cr
(G-L)p &= v \cr
Mp &= v \cr
p &= M^{-1}v \cr
}$$

Comment: but in your formula,how do you define the $[M]_{ij}$ value when $i =j $ and $i \neq j$? this is what i am confused

Comment: Note that $M=G-L$ and recall that $G$ is a diagonal matrix, so its off-diagonal elements are zero. To answer your question, simply do element-wise subtraction, i.e. $$M_{ij} = G_{ij} - L_{ij}$$

Comment: So $M_{ij}=G_{ij}-L_{ij}=(1+\frac{1}{\gamma _k})L_{ij}-L_{ij}=\frac{1}{\gamma _k}L_{ij}$,if that, $M_{ij}$ should only equal to $M_{ij}$ ,i mention in the question,when $i=j$,but where is the $ M_{ij}$  when $i \neq j ?$

Comment: No. $G$ is _diagonal_ that means that $G_{ij}=0$ when $i\ne j$.